# How to export React native code for windows platform

Tags: reactjs, react-native, windows-phone, hybrid-mobile-app, nativeapplication

I am having react native code which is running on both iOS & Android. Also I have used some dependencies like image picker or other but now I have to run that application in windows phone also so for this I followed this link for set up a dummy application in windows machine 
https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-for-windows-ba23a4be90b6

It was successfully done. There was no problem but when I am running for my existing React native application. It is throwing errors related to dependencies which were supported in both iOS & Android.

No issue my existing code is working fine in windows but those third paty libraries are not supported in windows.

As of now I have used this library to hide white screen in React for both Android & iOS  https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

My problem is that it is throwing error when using this library code for windows application else perfectly working in android & ios.(all third party libraries used in the existing react native code are not supporting in windows)

How can I run react native existing code for Windows Phone with all third party libraries.

Comment: I guess it's not easily possible (still in 2021). best way I know is to make a clone of the project and remove incompatible dependencies. so you will have two code bases instead of one.